# Windows Network Drive with samba disk looks disconnected after start up

Tags: windows-7, samba

I am using Samba under Ubuntu 18.04
It's all good and no problem to use.

Only one issue for me is..followed
As you see the picture, Windows does not recognize network drive by remote samba(Ubuntu 18.04) right after boot up.

[image: windows network drive picture, Please click !]

On the picture, 6 Drives are all samba disk but only one drive "Game(W:)" was recognized by "mouse double-clicking"

At samba side, status is like this

```
$ sudo smbstatus

Samba version 4.7.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18615   nobody       nogroup      192.168.0.4 (ipv4:192.168.0.4:1620)       SMB2_10           -                    -

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Game         18615   192.168.0.4   수  1월  2 09시 59분 16초 2019 KST -            -

Locked files:
Pid          Uid        DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18615        1006       DENY_NONE  0x100080    RDONLY     NONE             /home/Game/share_samba   .   Wed Jan  2 09:59:18 2019
```

My windows recognize the network drive disk by some event like "mouse clicking" or "keyboard button pushing"

I think this behavior is not normal since other usb external disk always recognized once it's linked.

Can anyone help on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with `net use` command and one small script. You can add unlimited shares in same way:

```
:CHECKFOLDER1
net use S: \\server1\share /Y
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL
IF NOT EXIST S: GOTO CHECKFOLDER1

:CHECKFOLDER2
net use S: \\server2\share /Y
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL
IF NOT EXIST T: GOTO CHECKFOLDER2
```

Insert the above code in .bat file and put in startup folder. To open this folder, press Win+R and type `shell:startup` command.

In the future, this script will run automatically on startup and try to "mount" these shares in every 5 seconds. It will exit, if shares are available.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will do it as you instruct